# Is it possible to show custom content in Tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to insert content NOT loaded from a url, into a tab after creating a new tab by using;

```
chrome.tabs.create(object createProperties, function callback)
```

Can this be done, or is there any other way to achieve the required effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, sort of. Each tab in Chrome must have some url, even a blank page. You can create a tab linked to html page from your extension folder though, that's what would be a workaround.

So if you create a stub html page called "newTab.html" and put it into extension folder:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
                //build a page from received data
                if(request.param1 == "value1") {
                    //...
                }

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Then you can create a new tab linked to this page and send required data through messaging.

In background.html page:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: "newTab.html"}, function(tab){
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {param1:"value1", param2:"value2"});
});
```

Comment: And what if I want to load other content from their root element and not in the body element?

Comment: @MrThys What do you mean? You want to include some javascript or css file into the header? You can inject it through javascript. If you  concertize your task maybe I can give you more specific solution, but the main idea is to have empty html and do the rest with javascript.

Comment: For instance I want to load a RSS feed or XML document into the content window?

Comment: @MrThys How this XML will be used, just for display purposes? Maybe you can just inject it into `<pre>` element or replace `<` with `&lt;`? If not for display purposes then what would be the point in having XML without any URL? I am not sure how to make dynamic pure XML/RSS feed on a client side.

Comment: I have my reasons:P But after some research it seems that it is not possible (yet)